# Query returns additional rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this kind of table for simple chat:

```
messages table structure
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+------+
| id | to_user | from_user | message | read | sent |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------+------+
```

And i need to get list of each conversation which looks like that

```
Username ----  Message ---- Date
```

I am using this query to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `sent`
IN (
   SELECT MAX( `sent` )
   FROM `messages`
   WHERE `from_user` = '1' --id of user who is requesting the list
   OR `to_user` = '1'  --id of user who is requesting the list
   GROUP BY `to_user` , `from_user`
   )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And this works almost fine, my problem is that it returns me not the **last** message of that conversation but last message from each user so let's say user `1` and `2` is talking and i'm getting this list, this is what i get:

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+------+---------------------+
| id | to_user | from_user | message               | read | sent                |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+------+---------------------+
|  3 |       2 |         1 | Message 1 from user 1 |    0 | 2012-01-11 13:20:54 |
|  4 |       1 |         2 | Message 1 from user 2 |    0 | 2012-01-11 13:24:59 |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------------+------+---------------------+
```

And i would like to get only last message which is **4**, cause `sent` field is the highest in 4th record so how can i solve it?

**EDIT** After deleting `group by` i'm getting only one message even if user was talking with more than one user

Comment: See my answer for the *correct* answer (rather than the one you accepted, which is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
  FROM messages
  WHERE from_user = ?
  OR to_user = ?
  ORDER by from_user, to_user, sent DESC
) x
GROUP BY from_user, to_user
ORDER BY sent DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In mysql, a group by *without* aggregating the other columns returns the *first* row for each group. By selecting form an ordered row set (the inner query) we get the *most recent* row for each conversation.

Comment: actualy this makes things even worse, i don't need only 1 last message... i need to get last message of each conversation..

Comment: this does the same thing as my current query, it gets me two last messages from each conversation and i need to find a way to get only last, and when i think about it actualy gets last one, bet it's last message of each user, so i need to find a way to get only from one user it's kinda hard to explain...

Comment: @Linas I understand now! A conversation is beween A and B. You want the last message *between* then - either from A to B, or from B to A - the direction doesn't matter, only the combination of A and B. This is a very interesting problem, but luckily I have the solution - see edited answer. It just took a little more refinement at the end of the query.

Comment: yes this would be correct, but now it creates me another problem, you see i need to create history of all conversations user had, so this now gets me one last message, but i need to do this for each conversation that user had

Comment: your problem is that the same row will apply to *both* "from" and "to" users - that's a tough one. I've given you enough help I think. good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `sent`
IN (
   SELECT MAX( `sent` )
   FROM `messages`
   WHERE (`from_user` = '1' OR `to_user` = '1')
   )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

the groupby is going to conbine them i believe.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the last message from each user because you have done GROUP BY for both: to_user and from_user.

There is no need to use GROUP BY clause in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `group by` clause in your `in` statement--it's useless in this case. It's returning a `sent` timestamp for each distinct pairing of `to_user` and `from_user`. You really just want the max `sent` where `to_user` or `from_user` equal some value. Lose the `group by`, and you'll return exactly one record showing the latest message either to or from a user.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages`
WHERE `sent`
IN (
   SELECT MAX( `sent` )
   FROM `messages`
   WHERE `from_user` = '1' --id of user who is requesting the list
   OR `to_user` = '1'  --id of user who is requesting the list
   )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually work - it will return all messages sent at that time, no matter who sent/received it